# Error: "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" when looping sns relplots

Tags: python, loops, seaborn

I've got a DataFrame that is structured similar to this one but with more variables:

```
  {'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00')},
 'Share': {0: 'nflx',
  1: 'aapl',
  2: 'amzn',
  3: 'nflx',
  4: 'aapl',
  5: 'amzn',
  6: 'nflx',
  7: 'aapl',
  8: 'amzn'},
 'x': {0: 534,
  1: 126,
  2: 3270,
  3: 590,
  4: 172,
  5: 3059,
  6: 552,
  7: 160,
  8: 3462}}
```

I'm trying to loop sns relplots but getting the error "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Code I've tried:

```
for i in [df["x"], df["y"], df["z"]]:
    sns.relplot(data=df.reset_index(),
        x="Date",
        y=i,
        hue="Share",
        kind="line",
        height=10,
        aspect=1.7).savefig("{i}.png");
```

I know the error tells me that index has duplicates but to my knowledge it should be temporary gone with the "reset_index()". Moreover I think I have to index the date variable in order to do some of the variable specific calculations. Is the issue the plot code or what's the solution?

Comment: `y` needs to be a column name, not a `pandas.Series`: [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcPrj.png). You can slice the columns to get the desired names: (e.g. `df.columns[3:]`)

Comment: `y=` *can* be a `pandas.Series` object, but it's giving you trouble here because it still has the duplicate index from the original dataframe. That said, this code seems like it would be cleaner if you looped over column names instead of column series.